# An easy way to send a file from one app to another (on a different device)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

What's the easiest way to transfer a file between two apps running on two different devices? The app is written in Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a database. File will be saved on cloud and from your app you can update it.

Like from X device you read the file parse it to `JSON` and `POST` to database.

Then from Y device you can request to database to return that file. That will be returned as `JSON` than you can read and map at your model and access the file datas using `yourModel.yourField()` .

Comment: Of course I can deploy a dedicated server and implement a mechanism like that. That would hardly qualify as an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your files on a Database such as [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage?hl=en) which allows you to store different file formats

You can then add more files from any device running your Flutter App & make network calls

Comment: How easy it is to share files stored in firebase with other users?